# How to detect the brightness programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ipad, brightness

I am creating an application for iPad which can change the images by detecting the brightness of the room. So I want to know is there a way to detect the brightness of the room ?

Comment: Using the camera or the built in iPad sensor?

Comment: I think this can be done with device integration with IOkit. If anybody knows about this please respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to take the average brightness of some set of pixels in your image. If you have an image with RGB pixels, you can get the brightness by adding the weighted components. A common weighting is 30% red, 59% green, 11% blue:

```
brightness = pixel.red * 0.3 + pixel.green * 0.59 + pixel.blue * 0.11;
```

Depending on the variations in your image, how accurate a measure you need, the resolution of your image, etc. you can average a sample of pixels from around the image, or just average all of them.

Comment: The question is how to detect the brightness _of the room_. But your idea could work if the camera were to be used for taking an image (once every 15 seconds) and then analysing that. ;-)